# Increase line thickness of x-axis ggplot theme

Tags: ggplot2, themes

I created my own theme and now I want to increase the thickness of the line of the x axis. I tried to do this with the axis.line.x argument, which seems like the proper thing to do. However, this code does nothing. Anyone has an idea of what goes wrong here?

```
library(ggplot2)                                           #create graph
library(ggthemes)                                          #create graph
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)                                             #dataframe manipulation
library(plyr)                                              #factor names                 

# dataset
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
df$am <- as.factor(df$am)
df$am <- revalue(df$am, c("0"="Automatic", "1"="Manual"))

# define color sets ukleur
uwvPalet <- c("#0078D2",               #lichtblauw 
          "#003282",               #donkerblauw
          "#C4D600")               #geel

# generating new theme
theme_uwv <- 

  function(base_size = 22,                                                     #general font size
       base_family = "Verdana"){                                           #general font type

  theme_hc(base_size = base_size,                                          #basic theme to start from
           base_family = base_family)   %+replace%

     theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
     axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.text = element_text(color = rgb(0, 0, 0, 
                                                     maxColorValue = 255),
                                                     size = rel(0.5)),
                    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                    axis.line.x  = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 2),
                    legend.title = element_blank(),
                    legend.text = element_text(family = "Verdana",
                                               color = "black",
                                               size = 12,
                                               face = "plain"),
                    legend.text.align = 0.5, 
                    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, 'cm'),                   #spacing between legend categories
                    panel.grid.major = element_line(rgb(105, 105, 105, 
                                                    maxColorValue = 255),
                                       linetype = "solid"),   
                    panel.grid.minor = element_line(rgb(105, 105, 105, 
                                                    maxColorValue = 255),
                                       linetype = "dotted", 
                                       size = rel(4)),   

  complete = TRUE
)
  }

theme_uwv <- list(theme_uwv(), scale_fill_manual(values = uwvPalet))         #add default colour set

 # Grouped bar plot
ggplot(df, aes(fill = cyl, x = am, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
  theme_uwv
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some extra theme components that I think were overwriting what you were trying to do. I have tried reproducing your code and this is what I came up with.

```
theme_uwv <- 

function(base_size = 22,                                                     
         base_family = "Verdana"){                                           

  theme_hc(base_size = base_size,                                         
         base_family = base_family)   %+replace%

  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color = rgb(0, 0, 0, 
                                             maxColorValue = 255),
                                 size = rel(0.5)),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Verdana",
                                   color = "black",
                                   size = 12,
                                   face = "plain"),
        legend.text.align = 0.5, 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 1.5, rgb(105, 105, 105, 
                                              maxColorValue = 255),
                                          linetype = "solid"), #added part that 
                                                               should make it work
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        complete = TRUE
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Edgar, thank you for thinking along. Unfortunately, this code makes ALL horizontal gridlines thick. I only want the horizontal line that depicts the x-axis to be thicker. The other grid lines should stay relatively thin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to add to your theme the idea of:

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))
```

However, for that you need to make a list consisting of: on the one hand the ggproto object (geom_hline), and on the other hand your theme-elements. Then you can just add this theme_uwv() to your ggplot and it will draw a line at x-axis (which you could make bolder and so on in the same way).

Here the overall code:

```
library(ggplot2)                                           #create graph
library(ggthemes)                                          #create graph
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)                                             #dataframe manipulation
library(plyr)                                              #factor names                 

# dataset
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
df$am <- as.factor(df$am)
df$am <- revalue(df$am, c("0"="Automatic", "1"="Manual"))

# define color sets ukleur
uwvPalet <- c("#0078D2",               #lichtblauw 
          "#003282",               #donkerblauw
          "#C4D600")               #geel

# generating new theme
theme_uwv <- 

  function(base_size = 22,                                                     #general font size
       base_family = "Verdana"){                                           #general font type

  list(geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)),
        theme_bw(base_size = base_size,                                          #basic theme to start from
                 base_family = base_family)   %+replace%
     theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
     axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.text = element_text(color = rgb(0, 0, 0, 
                                                     maxColorValue = 255),
                                                     size = rel(0.5)),
                    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                    axis.line.x  = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 2),
                    legend.title = element_blank(),
                    legend.text = element_text(family = "Verdana",
                                               color = "black",
                                               size = 12,
                                               face = "plain"),
                    legend.text.align = 0.5, 
                    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, 'cm'),                   #spacing between legend categories
                    panel.grid.major = element_line(rgb(105, 105, 105, 
                                                    maxColorValue = 255),
                                       linetype = "solid"),   
                    panel.grid.minor = element_line(rgb(105, 105, 105, 
                                                    maxColorValue = 255),
                                       linetype = "dotted", 
                                       size = rel(4)),   

  complete = TRUE
)
  }

theme_uwv <- list(theme_uwv(), scale_fill_manual(values = uwvPalet))         #add default colour set

 # Grouped bar plot
ggplot(df, aes(fill = cyl, x = am, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
  theme_uwv
```